# Ubuntu 14.04 (DB with W10) Ethernet will not attach to network...until it does

Tags: networking, ethernet

So I have been having network problems since I configured Grub to manage my dual boot machine. Ethernet will not configure dhcp automatically when Ubuntu is booted up, and setting the IP manually doesn't work either. A manual IP for my wlan does work, however. I have completely uninstalled network-manager and reinstalled with all of its other packages and still no dice.

However, I left my Linux side online overnight last night, and this morning, dhcp had assigned a valid IP and ethernet was working properly. Upon rebooting, it failed to connect and started all over again.

I've been through the first dozen or so related problems here and on other forums (fora?) and can't seem to find a solution.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:bc:11:c6:54  
      inet6 addr: fe80::21f:bcff:fe11:c654/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:289293 (289.2 KB)  TX bytes:104157 (104.1 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000

  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 00:1f:bc:11:c6:54
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.5-k duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:40 memory:fb200000-fb21ffff memory:fb239000-fb239fff ioport:f020(size=32)
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:1
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: 74:da:38:56:1d:d0
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.2.0-41-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.50 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Thanks for any help! Let me know if there's any other diagnostic that would be helpful to see.